# Connection reset error when checking for updates in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm getting a connection reset error when I click check for updates. I checked my proxy setting, no proxy is selected. Are there any other resolutions?

Answer (score 0):

Please select offline mode for android studio.hope that will solve your issue.

File -- >  Settings-->Build,Execution and Deployment--> Gradle

than check the  offline work checkbox

Comment: I done the above thing which you said, still I am getting error : **Gradle 'Project1' Project refresh failed** Error : Connection reset